# Getting image url from JSON response using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to fetch an image from an API using AngularJS.

I'm using a link to trigger the $http function, and trying to parse the image url from the JSON response back into the HTML, but I think I'm missing something, as the response comes back OK, but the img url doesn't get "in place".

Here's my html:

```
<a ng-click="getImages()">Image: <img src="{{album.image.2.#text}}" /></a>
```

My JS:

```
$scope.getImages = function () {
  $http.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=%%%&artist=vnv+nation&album=empires&format=json').
    success(function(data4) {
        $scope.images = data4;
    });
}
```

And a example of JSON response:

```
album: {name:Empires, artist:VNV Nation, id:2025273, mbid:0c3ccb9f-e6c4-419d-934e-02e3be8a08c9,…}
artist: "VNV Nation"
id: "2025273"
image: [{#text:http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/93873429.png, size:small},…]
   0: {#text:http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/93873429.png, size:small}
   1: {#text:http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/93873429.png, size:medium}
   2: {#text:http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/174s/93873429.png, size:large}
       #text: "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/174s/93873429.png"
       size: "large"
```

**EDIT**: I made a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BOPtqIIZYto8iopHAr3a?p=preview). You can see in the console how the json response is called correctly, but the image url is still not being shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [ng-src](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc):

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The
>   ngSrc directive solves this problem.

```
<img ng-src="{{album.image.2.#text}}" />
```

Another problem is the `#` character and number. You could fix this with bracket notation:

```
<img ng-src="{{album.image[2]['#text']}}" />
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/8UkazXhWd9KKhyfyfmVD?p=preview)

Comment: Hi! I've tried with ng-src, and it is still not getting populated with the proper url. Given the JSON example, is the route (album.image.2.#text) correct? Also, for whatever reason, with #text it brakes all my Angular code, without hash, it doesn't...

Comment: @Eric Mitjans: I recommend that you avoid special characters in your property names. Ifi there is a special character, you could try bracket notation syntax: `album.image[2]["#text"]`. And about the path, looking at your source code, I guess: `images.image[2]["#text"]`

Comment: The response comes from a 3rd party API, so unfortunately there's not much I can do about the special characters... I've created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BOPtqIIZYto8iopHAr3a?p=preview), maybe is easier to see the problem :S

Comment: @Eric Mitjans: I did not know that you get the data from a 3rd party API. In this case, you run into cross-domain problem. Does your 3rd party support JSONP?

Comment: @Eric Mitjans: I added a working demo with same domain. In your case, your 3rd must support JSONP to make it work.